# How to determine if any value in one array, is lower than any value in another array, for a given bin?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare, line

I am trying to compare different lines, to know if one is above the other one, and if not, at which `x` this change happens.

If I had the same `x` values and same length, that would be very easy and only difference in `y`s of the lines.

But I have different `x` values for different lines, and the vectors do not have the same length, but `x` intervals are the same for all curves.

As a very simple example I use the following data:

```py
#curve 1: len = 9
x1 = np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
y1 = np.array([100,101,110,130,132,170,190,192,210])

#curve 2: len = 10
x2 = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
y2 = np.array([90,210,211,250,260,261,265,180,200,210])

#curve 3: len = 8
x3 = np.array([7.3,8.3,9.3,10.3,11.3,12.3,13.3,14.3])
y3 = np.array([300,250,270,350,380,400,390,380])
```

They are supposed to be 2 regression lines. In this simple example, the result is supposed to be that **Curve 2 has higher values than curve 1 in all `x` range**.

I was trying to bin `x` in the range of 2.5-12.5 with the bin length of 1 to compare the corresponding `y`s in each bin.

My actual data are big, and this comparison needs to be done many times, so I need to find a solution that does not take much time.

### Plot

- Plot of data for given x-axis

```py
plt.figure(figsize=(6, 6))
plt.plot(x1, y1, marker='o', label='y1')
plt.plot(x2, y2, marker='o', label='y2')
plt.plot(x3, y3, marker='o', label='y3')
plt.xticks(range(15))
plt.legend()
plt.grid()
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Functions

- `def get_new_x` uses [`np.digitize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) to re-bin the x-axis values.
- `def get_comparison` adds a column of Booleans for each two columns compared

  - Currently each new column is added to the main dataframe, `df`, however this can be updated to be a separate `comparison` dataframe.
  - `combs` is a list column combinations

    - `[Index(['y1', 'y2'], dtype='object'), Index(['y2', 'y3'], dtype='object')]`

```py
# function to create the bins 
def get_bins(x_arrays: List[np.array]) -> np.array:
    bin_len = np.diff(x_arrays[0][:2])  # calculate bin length 
    all_x = np.concatenate(x_arrays)  # join arrays
    min_x = min(all_x)  # get min
    max_x = max(all_x)  # get max
    return np.arange(min_x, max_x + bin_len, bin_len)


# function using np.digitize to bin the old x-axis into new bins
def get_new_x(x_arrays: List[np.array]) -> List[np.array]:
    bins = get_bins(x_arrays)  # get the bins
    x_new = list()
    for x in x_arrays:
        x_new.append(bins[np.digitize(np.round(x), bins, right=True)])  # determine bins
    return x_new


# function to create dataframe for arrays with new x-axis as index
def get_df(x_arrays: List[np.array], y_arrays: List[np.array]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    x_new = get_new_x(x_arrays)
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(y, columns=[f'y{i+1}'], index=x_new[i]) for i, y in enumerate(y_arrays)], axis=1)


# compare each successive column of the dataframe
# if the left column is greater than the right column, then True
def get_comparison(df: pd.DataFrame):
    cols = df.columns
    combs = [cols[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(cols), 1) if i < len(cols)-1]
    for comb in combs:
        df[f'{comb[0]} > {comb[1]}'] = df[comb[0]] > df[comb[1]]
```

### Call functions:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# put the arrays into a list
y = [y1, y2, y3]
x = [x1, x2, x3]

# call get_df
df = get_df(x, y)

# call get_comparison
get_comparison(df)

# get only the index of True values with Boolean indexing
for col in df.columns[3:]:
    vals = df.index[df[col]].tolist()
    if vals:
        print(f'{col}: {vals}')

[out]:
y2 > y3: [8.0]
```

## display(df)

```
         y1     y2     y3  y1 > y2  y2 > y3
3.0     NaN   90.0    NaN    False    False
4.0     NaN  210.0    NaN    False    False
5.0   100.0  211.0    NaN    False    False
6.0   101.0  250.0    NaN    False    False
7.0   110.0  260.0  300.0    False    False
8.0   130.0  261.0  250.0    False     True
9.0   132.0  265.0  270.0    False    False
10.0  170.0  180.0  350.0    False    False
11.0  190.0  200.0  380.0    False    False
12.0  192.0  210.0  400.0    False    False
13.0  210.0    NaN  390.0    False    False
14.0    NaN    NaN  380.0    False    False
```

### Plot

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))

# add markers for problem values
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns[3:], 1):
    vals = df.iloc[:, i][df[col]]
    if not vals.empty:
        ax.scatter(vals.index, vals.values, color='red', s=110, label='bad')

df.iloc[:, :3].plot(marker='o', ax=ax)  # plot the dataframe        

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.xticks(range(16))
plt.title('y-values plotted against rebinned x-values')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I had in my mind when I first asked the question, but couldn't make it work back then. My idea is based on binning y1 and y2 based on x and comparing these two in each bin. So, as an example I have 3 curves and I want to compare them. The only similar thing among these curves is `delta x` (bin length) which is 1 here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as  pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#curve 1
x1 = np.array([5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13])
y1 = np.array([100,101,110,130,132,170,190,192,210])

#curve 2
x2 = np.array([3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
y2 = np.array([90,210,211,250,260,261,265,180,200,210])

#curve 3
x3 = np.array([7.3,8.3,9.3,10.3,11.3,12.3,13.3,14.3])
y3 = np.array([300,250,270,350,380,400,390,380])

bin_length = 1
# x values have same intervals both in x1 and x2

x_min = min(x1[0],x2[0],x3[0])-bin_length/2
x_max = max(x1[-1],x2[-1],x3[-1])+bin_length/2

bins = np.arange(x_min,x_max+bin_length,bin_length)

# bin mid points to use as index
bin_mid = []
for i in range(len(bins)-1):
    # compute mid point of the bins
    bin_mid.append((bins[i] + bins[i+1])/2)

# This function bins y based on binning x
def bin_fun(x,y,bins,bin_length):
    c = list(zip(x, y))
    # define final out put of the function
    final_y_binning = []
    # define a list for holding members of each bin
    bined_y_members = []
    # compute length of each bin

    for i in range(len(bins)-1):
        # compute high and low threshold of the bins
        low_threshold = bins[i]
        high_threshold = bins[i+1]

        # bin y according to x
        for member in c:
            if (member[0] < high_threshold and member[0] >= low_threshold):
                bined_y_members.append(member[1])
                
        final_y_binning.append(bined_y_members)
        # fill out the container of the bin members

        bined_y_members=[]

        df = pd.DataFrame(final_y_binning)
    return(df)


binned_y =pd.DataFrame(columns=[1,2,3])

Y1 = bin_fun(x1,y1,bins, bin_length)
Y1.columns =[1]

Y2 = bin_fun(x2,y2,bins, bin_length)
Y2.columns =[2]

Y3 = bin_fun(x3,y3,bins, bin_length)
Y3.columns =[3]

binned_y = binned_y.append(Y1)
binned_y[2] = Y2
binned_y[3] = Y3

binned_y.index = bin_mid

print(binned_y)

# comparing curve 2 and curve 1
for i in binned_y.index:
    if (binned_y.loc[i][2]-binned_y.loc[i][1]<0):
        print(i)

 # comparing curve 3 and curve 2
for i in binned_y.index:
    if (binned_y.loc[i][3]-binned_y.loc[i][2]<0):
        print(i)
```

This returns 8 which is the index that y3<y2`

### `binned_y`

```py
          1      2      3
3.0     NaN   90.0    NaN
4.0     NaN  210.0    NaN
5.0   100.0  211.0    NaN
6.0   101.0  250.0    NaN
7.0   110.0  260.0  300.0
8.0   130.0  261.0  250.0
9.0   132.0  265.0  270.0
10.0  170.0  180.0  350.0
11.0  190.0  200.0  380.0
12.0  192.0  210.0  400.0
13.0  210.0    NaN  390.0
14.0    NaN    NaN  380.0
15.0    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

### plot

```py
binned_y.plot(marker='o', figsize=(6, 6))  # plot the dataframe
plt.legend(labels=['y1', 'y2', 'y3'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
plt.xticks(range(16))
plt.grid()
```

[image]